# loss and accurancy stay the same after training

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I have an lstm model for human activity recognition task using data from sensors.

when I train my model the loss and accuracy stays the same. Which is the problem in this case in general?

I try to change the learning rate but the results are the same,

below is the model that I use

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(64, return_sequences=True, recurrent_regularizer=l2(0.0015), input_shape=(timestamps, 
input_dim)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(LSTM(64, recurrent_regularizer=l2(0.0015), input_shape=(timesteps,input_dim)))


model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))

model.add(Dense(n_classes, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate = 0.0025), loss = 
'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', 
metrics = ['accuracy'])

history =model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=100)
```

the dataset is balanced across classes and I have used the standard scaller

```
lying           68704
running         68704
walking         68704
climbingdown    68704
jumping         68704
climbingup      68704
standing        68704
sitting         68704
```

Comment: Can you please tell about your dataset?

Comment: yes i edit the answer, thanks

Comment: Okey. Can you please tell about `y_train`. Does it look like an array that contains numbers from 0 to *n_classes*? Or is it a matrix with size *n_classes* x *n_samples*?

Comment: yeah like this 
array([0, 7, 2, ..., 3, 1, 0])

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't say much without your entire code. Also, you could add a link to the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

i find the solution after remove the l2 regularization. I do not know exactly how this work but I gonna investigate the issue a little more